# Query the list of supported regions in aws amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How to get list available regions from amazon?
Before I tried next query

```
https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeRegions&AWSAccessKeyId=****&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=1&Version=2013-08-15
```

But I get "AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials" and I don't sure that it correct query.

Comment: Which "Signature Version" are you trying to use? Your example is using SignatureVersion=1, which is invalid. Refer to this link for version 2 signing (which is not the latest version) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

Comment: I change SignatureVersion but I have some error

Comment: Post your code that creates your signing. Did you review the documentation link? Compare you example with the documentation. You will notice that you are missing &Signature=

Answer (score 0):

Your Question Does not seem to specify what services you need to use and how but here is generic example from `AWS CLI`:

Using `describe-regions` will give answer to your question , example to describe region names only:
`aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].{Name:RegionName}' --output text` output will be like:

```
ap-south-1
eu-west-1
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2
eu-central-1
ap-northeast-2
ap-northeast-1
us-east-1
sa-east-1
us-west-1
us-west-2
```

This is the [AWS CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html) that you can refer.